# Not Redirecting after Post

Tags: php, redirect

I have a post php page that once the data posts to the database I want it to redirect the user to a new page and display the results of the last_id for the record they just inserted.

I can verify the data posts just fine, but the redirect is not working. It just sits there and looks very sad. It worked once, but now I can't seem to get it to work again.

The fragment that is in question is:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
         $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
          echo ' <head> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://vmcnucmed.cvm.umn.edu/patientinjection/view_inj_info.php?id=' . $last_id;'"></head>
          Patient Added Successfully. <br /><br />Database ID: ' . $last_id;'<br>';
 }
```

The script in its entirety is:

```
<title>Post Patient Injection Information</title>
<?php
$erors = array();                      // set an empty array that will contains the errors

// Check for form submission
if (isset($_POST['patientID']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) && isset($_POST['patientname'])&& isset($_POST['dose'])) {
  // remove tags and whitespace from the beginning and end of form data
  $_POST = array_map("strip_tags", $_POST);
  $_POST = array_map("trim", $_POST);

  // chech if all form fields are filled in correctly
  // (minimum number of characters in "patientID")
  if (strlen($_POST['patientID'])<3) $erors[] = 'Patient ID must contain at least 3 characters.';


  // if no errors ($error array empty)
  if(count($erors)<1) {
    // connect to the "tests" database
    $conn = new mysqli('somehost', 'someuser', 'somepassword', 'somedatabase');

    // check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // store the values in an Array, escaping special characters for use in the SQL statement
    $adds['pkgnumberID'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['pkgnumberID']);  // package number ID
    $adds['rxnumber'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['rxnumber']);  // patient prescription number
    $adds['patientID'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['patientID']);  // Patient ID / MRN number 
    $adds['lastname'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);  // patient last name
    $adds['patientname'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['patientname']);  // patient name
    $adds['isotope'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['isotope']);  // isotope injected
    $adds['radiopharmaceutical'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['radiopharmaceutical']);  // radiopharmaceutical injected
    $adds['dose'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['dose']);  // dose injected
    $adds['datetimestated'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['datetimestated']);  // date/time stated activity
    $adds['datetimeadmin'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['datetimeadmin']);  // date/time administered
    $adds['adminby'] = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['adminby']);  // administered by

    // sql query for INSERT INTO tbl_patientdoseinformation
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_patientdoseinformation` (`pkgnumberID`,`rxnumber`,`patientID`,`lastname`,`patientname`,`isotope`,`radiopharmaceutical`,`dose`,`datetimestated`,`datetimeadmin`,`adminby`) 
    VALUES ('". $adds['pkgnumberID']. "','". $adds['rxnumber']. "','". $adds['patientID']. "','". strtoupper($adds['lastname']). "','". strtoupper($adds['patientname']). "','". $adds['isotope']. "','". $adds['radiopharmaceutical']. "','". $adds['dose']. "','". $adds['datetimestated']. "','". $adds['datetimeadmin']. "','". $adds['adminby']. "')"; 

    // Performs the $sql query on the server to insert the values
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
      echo ' <head> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://vmcnucmed.cvm.umn.edu/patientinjection/view_inj_info.php?id=' . $last_id;'"></head>
      Patient Added Successfully. <br /><br />Database ID: ' . $last_id;'<br>';
    }
    else {
      echo 'Error: '. $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
  }
  else {
    // else, if errors, it adds them in string format and print it
    echo implode('<br />', $erors);
  }
}
else {
  echo 'No data from form';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice for redirection after post is to send a Location header with 302 status code instead of redirecting with HTML meta tag:

```
header(
    'Location: http://vmcnucmed.cvm.umn.edu/patientinjection/view_inj_info.php?id=' . $last_id, 
    TRUE, // rewrite existing Location header
    302 // set status code
);
```

The 302 code will force the browser to reload the page with GET instead of POST request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll get better results if you return the redirect in the response headers like so...

```
header( 'Location: http://vmcnucmed.cvm.umn.edu/patientinjection/view_inj_info.php?id=' . $last_id );
```